# Proving $\{x\otimes n\mid n\in N, xn = 0 \} \cong \{n\in N\mid xn = 0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I was trying to follow a proof where i got stuck at one particular part which i would really like to understand.

Let $(x)\subseteq A$ be the principle ideal for a non-zero divisor $x\in A$ and $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$.

Suppose we had \begin{align*} \varphi\colon (x)\otimes_A N &\to A\otimes_A N\\ x\otimes n &\mapsto xn \end{align*} where we identify $A\otimes_A N \cong N$.

Then $$\ker \varphi = \{x\otimes n\mid n\in N, xn = 0 \}$$ and we want to prove that

$$\ker \varphi \cong \{n\in N\mid xn = 0\}$$

---

**My question:** The solution says that it's sufficient to verify that

\begin{align*} \psi\colon N&\to (x)\otimes_A N \\ n&\mapsto x\otimes n \end{align*}
is an isomorphism.

Why is that? Why does $\psi$ being an isomorphism imply

$$\ker \varphi \cong \{n\in N\mid xn = 0\}$$

Even if it might appear trivial, please help me understanding the underlying observation, because i'm afraid that i'm missing something very fundamental here.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the composition $f = \varphi \circ \psi : N \to N$ sending $n$ to $xn$.

You can verify since $\psi$ is an isomorphism that $\ker f \cong \ker \varphi$. Now, $\ker f = \{n \in N\,\,\vert\,\, xn = 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks rushy, that makes sense.